# NASM errors in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, nasm

I started reading [the following book](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) about operating systems and I'm having some issues building the first assembly program example with the instructions that the author gives (page 12-13):

```
loop:
   jmp loop

times 510-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

I get the following errors when running the `nasm` command they provide in the book:

```
$ nasm boot_sector.asm -f bin -o boot_sector.bin
boot_sector.asm:1: error: expression syntax error
boot_sector.asm:2: error: expression syntax error
```

The error seems to be related with the `loop` tag and the jump right after it, but I'm clueless about what is wrong/missing (just starting with assembly).

I'm building the program in a MacBook Pro with Mavericks.

**UPDATE:** Using `jmp $` instead of

```
loop:
  jmp loop
```

Works fine, although don't know why.

Comment: The x86 instruction set includes one called 'loop'. This is probably confusing the assembler. Use some other id for the label.

Comment: @Gene Thanks a lot! The ID it's indeed confusing the assembler. Can you set this as an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x86 instruction set includes one named 'loop'.  So a label with the same name is probably confusing the assembler. Try a different id for the label.